# Can Rails act as a reverse proxy for hosting a domain on mysite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tumblr, reverse-proxy

I have mysite.com. Currently my blog is blog.mysite.com

I want my blog to be: mysite.com/blog - which would point to a tumblr blog.

Is it possible to use Rails as a reverse proxy that would main the URL structure at mysite.com/blog and show tumblr content, maintaining the mysite.com/blog url and article urls... Not redirecting to tumblr's URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible but a very heavy solution. What you need to do is define method on controller that would fetch the remote content and render it.

```
require 'net/http'

class TunblrController<ApplicationController
  def index
    uri = URI('http://tumlbr.com/myblog')
    html = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    render :html=>html
  end
end
```

that being said, you are much better off doing it using Nginx, HAProxy or other similar solutions

Comment: What do you think of this? Still to heavy? https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy

Comment: this is rack based solution that doesn't require all the heavy weight of rails, however why would you want to do it even on the rack level rather than on web server level?

Comment: I'm on EC2,NINGX,Loading Balancing w a tumblr blog and haven't been able to find any tutorials showing the steps. Concerned about the risk

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any info on how to use a URL pattern?